# Advice for Exporting DataGridview To Excel

Tags: c#

I try to export `DataGridview` to Excel. My code is :

```
private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
{
    string stOutput = "";
    // Export titles:
    string sHeaders = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
        sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
    stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
    // Export data.
    for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        string stLine = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
        stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
    }
    Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
    byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Code for button for exporting to Excel :

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
sfd.FileName = "export.xls";
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //ToCsV(dataGridView1, @"c:\export.xls");
    ToCsV(dataGridView1, sfd.FileName); // Here dataGridview1 is your grid view name 
}
```

I need to use UTF-8 instead of UTF-16. Becaue my table contains Arabic . So how should I do that

Comment: Any one Can help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

use

`Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);`

```
This code produces the following output.

Info.CodePage      Info.Name                    Info.DisplayName
37                 IBM037                       IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada)       
437                IBM437                       OEM United States            
500                IBM500                       IBM EBCDIC (International)    
708                ASMO-708                     Arabic (ASMO 708)            
720                DOS-720                      Arabic (DOS)                 
737                ibm737                       Greek (DOS)                  
775                ibm775                       Baltic (DOS)                 
850                ibm850                       Western European (DOS)       
852                ibm852                       Central European (DOS)       
855                IBM855                       OEM Cyrillic                 
857                ibm857                       Turkish (DOS)                
858                IBM00858                     OEM Multilingual Latin I     
860                IBM860                       Portuguese (DOS)             
861                ibm861                       Icelandic (DOS)              
862                DOS-862                      Hebrew (DOS)                 
863                IBM863                       French Canadian (DOS)        
864                IBM864                       Arabic (864)                 
865                IBM865                       Nordic (DOS)                 
866                cp866                        Cyrillic (DOS)               
869                ibm869                       Greek, Modern (DOS)          
870                IBM870                       IBM EBCDIC (Multilingual Latin-2)    
874                windows-874                  Thai (Windows)               
875                cp875                        IBM EBCDIC (Greek Modern)    
932                shift_jis                    Japanese (Shift-JIS)         
936                gb2312                       Chinese Simplified (GB2312)    
949                ks_c_5601-1987               Korean                       
950                big5                         Chinese Traditional (Big5)    
1026               IBM1026                      IBM EBCDIC (Turkish Latin-5)    
1047               IBM01047                     IBM Latin-1                  
1140               IBM01140                     IBM EBCDIC (US-Canada-Euro)    
1141               IBM01141                     IBM EBCDIC (Germany-Euro)    
1142               IBM01142                     IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway-Euro)    
1143               IBM01143                     IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden-Euro)    
1144               IBM01144                     IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)      
1145               IBM01145                     IBM EBCDIC (Spain-Euro)      
1146               IBM01146                     IBM EBCDIC (UK-Euro)         
1147               IBM01147                     IBM EBCDIC (France-Euro)     
1148               IBM01148                     IBM EBCDIC (International-Euro)    
1149               IBM01149                     IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic-Euro)    
1200               utf-16                       Unicode                      
1201               unicodeFFFE                  Unicode (Big-Endian)         
1250               windows-1250                 Central European (Windows)    
1251               windows-1251                 Cyrillic (Windows)           
1252               Windows-1252                 Western European (Windows)    
1253               windows-1253                 Greek (Windows)              
1254               windows-1254                 Turkish (Windows)            
1255               windows-1255                 Hebrew (Windows)             
1256               windows-1256                 Arabic (Windows)             
1257               windows-1257                 Baltic (Windows)             
1258               windows-1258                 Vietnamese (Windows)         
1361               Johab                        Korean (Johab)               
10000              macintosh                    Western European (Mac)       
10001              x-mac-japanese               Japanese (Mac)               
10002              x-mac-chinesetrad            Chinese Traditional (Mac)    
10003              x-mac-korean                 Korean (Mac)                 
10004              x-mac-arabic                 Arabic (Mac)                 
10005              x-mac-hebrew                 Hebrew (Mac)                 
10006              x-mac-greek                  Greek (Mac)                  
10007              x-mac-cyrillic               Cyrillic (Mac)               
10008              x-mac-chinesesimp            Chinese Simplified (Mac)     
10010              x-mac-romanian               Romanian (Mac)               
10017              x-mac-ukrainian              Ukrainian (Mac)              
10021              x-mac-thai                   Thai (Mac)                   
10029              x-mac-ce                     Central European (Mac)       
10079              x-mac-icelandic              Icelandic (Mac)              
10081              x-mac-turkish                Turkish (Mac)                
10082              x-mac-croatian               Croatian (Mac)               
12000              utf-32                       Unicode (UTF-32)             
12001              utf-32BE                     Unicode (UTF-32 Big-Endian)    
20000              x-Chinese-CNS                Chinese Traditional (CNS)    
20001              x-cp20001                    TCA Taiwan                   
20002              x-Chinese-Eten               Chinese Traditional (Eten)    
20003              x-cp20003                    IBM5550 Taiwan               
20004              x-cp20004                    TeleText Taiwan              
20005              x-cp20005                    Wang Taiwan                  
20105              x-IA5                        Western European (IA5)       
20106              x-IA5-German                 German (IA5)                 
20107              x-IA5-Swedish                Swedish (IA5)                
20108              x-IA5-Norwegian              Norwegian (IA5)              
20127              us-ascii                     US-ASCII                     
20261              x-cp20261                    T.61                         
20269              x-cp20269                    ISO-6937                     
20273              IBM273                       IBM EBCDIC (Germany)         
20277              IBM277                       IBM EBCDIC (Denmark-Norway)    
20278              IBM278                       IBM EBCDIC (Finland-Sweden)    
20280              IBM280                       IBM EBCDIC (Italy)           
20284              IBM284                       IBM EBCDIC (Spain)           
20285              IBM285                       IBM EBCDIC (UK)              
20290              IBM290                       IBM EBCDIC (Japanese katakana)    
20297              IBM297                       IBM EBCDIC (France)          
20420              IBM420                       IBM EBCDIC (Arabic)          
20423              IBM423                       IBM EBCDIC (Greek)           
20424              IBM424                       IBM EBCDIC (Hebrew)          
20833              x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended      IBM EBCDIC (Korean Extended)    
20838              IBM-Thai                     IBM EBCDIC (Thai)            
20866              koi8-r                       Cyrillic (KOI8-R)            
20871              IBM871                       IBM EBCDIC (Icelandic)       
20880              IBM880                       IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Russian)    
20905              IBM905                       IBM EBCDIC (Turkish)         
20924              IBM00924                     IBM Latin-1                  
20932              EUC-JP                       Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)    
20936              x-cp20936                    Chinese Simplified (GB2312-80)    
20949              x-cp20949                    Korean Wansung               
21025              cp1025                       IBM EBCDIC (Cyrillic Serbian-Bulgarian)    
21866              koi8-u                       Cyrillic (KOI8-U)            
28591              iso-8859-1                   Western European (ISO)       
28592              iso-8859-2                   Central European (ISO)       
28593              iso-8859-3                   Latin 3 (ISO)                
28594              iso-8859-4                   Baltic (ISO)                 
28595              iso-8859-5                   Cyrillic (ISO)               
28596              iso-8859-6                   Arabic (ISO)                 
28597              iso-8859-7                   Greek (ISO)                  
28598              iso-8859-8                   Hebrew (ISO-Visual)          
28599              iso-8859-9                   Turkish (ISO)                
28603              iso-8859-13                  Estonian (ISO)               
28605              iso-8859-15                  Latin 9 (ISO)                
29001              x-Europa                     Europa                       
38598              iso-8859-8-i                 Hebrew (ISO-Logical)         
50220              iso-2022-jp                  Japanese (JIS)               
50221              csISO2022JP                  Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana)    
50222              iso-2022-jp                  Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)    
50225              iso-2022-kr                  Korean (ISO)                 
50227              x-cp50227                    Chinese Simplified (ISO-2022)    
51932              euc-jp                       Japanese (EUC)               
51936              EUC-CN                       Chinese Simplified (EUC)     
51949              euc-kr                       Korean (EUC)                 
52936              hz-gb-2312                   Chinese Simplified (HZ)      
54936              GB18030                      Chinese Simplified (GB18030)    
57002              x-iscii-de                   ISCII Devanagari             
57003              x-iscii-be                   ISCII Bengali                
57004              x-iscii-ta                   ISCII Tamil                  
57005              x-iscii-te                   ISCII Telugu                 
57006              x-iscii-as                   ISCII Assamese               
57007              x-iscii-or                   ISCII Oriya                  
57008              x-iscii-ka                   ISCII Kannada                
57009              x-iscii-ma                   ISCII Malayalam              
57010              x-iscii-gu                   ISCII Gujarati               
57011              x-iscii-pa                   ISCII Punjabi                
65000              utf-7                        Unicode (UTF-7)              
65001              utf-8                        Unicode (UTF-8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same Code.. Same problem..
I ended up using another Encoding.. Problem Solved using this :

```
byte[] output = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(stOutput);
```

instead of

```
Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
```

Try this and let me know..